# Border appears when click on input with OnClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I am just creating an own website with a login and I have to input-tags of text-type. And I just want when clicking on them that a border appears also when the mouse is anywhere else.
I hope someone can help me
thank you in advance

Edit:
html code

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input class="login" name="user" type="text" placeholder="Benutzername">
    <input class="login_pw" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Passwort"><br>
    <br><input class="submit" name="login" value="Anmelden" type="submit">
</form>
```

CSS code

```
.login {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.login_pw {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}
```

Comment: Please post your attempts / code so we can have a detailed look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out adding this in css:

```
**input.middle:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}**

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```